# My phone denies certain file types when sending from PC via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

My Samsung Galaxy Ace has the latest official CyanogenMod nightly. I have Windows XP, a bluetooth dongle, and bluesoleil drivers.

I am able to send images and apk files from my pc to my phone. But when I try to send an epub file, or a 7z file, my pc says:

"Access is denied. Please make sure you have the proper right to access the files or folders."

So I tried to create a compressed file and instead of using 7z, I used .zip. And it was able to send it. So I'm positive that my phone has a list of allowed file types to be received. Is there any way to edit it? Thanks.

PS: I tried declining a file (that successfully went through), and it gave the same access denied error on my pc. So I believe that my phone is automatically denying certain file types. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because there's certain data types that are allowed through such as JPG, PNG, zip, pdf, text, anything else is filtered out and denied for the simple reason of security and to prevent malicious exploitation of transferring a binary executable across it for example.

You cannot edit them as they are baked into the ROM and built at compile time.

Look in `packages/app/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/Constants.java`:

```
public static final String[] ACCEPTABLE_SHARE_INBOUND_TYPES = new String[] {
        "*",
        "image/*",
        "video/*",
        "audio/*",
        "text/x-vcard",
        "text/plain",
        "text/html",
        "application/zip",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        "application/msword",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
        "application/pdf",
    };
```

It is similar in principle to the MIME types found in among Web servers, such as uploading a PNG or JPG to a site. The filters would be in place to prevent Window binaries to be uploaded.